# Отправка смс сайта на почту используя Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

Использую codeigniter 3. И мне нужно сделать отправку с формы смс на почту @gmail. Решил использовать **$this->load->library('email')**. Cделал как в документации:

```
$this->load->library('email')
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('C сайта');
$this->email->to('nnn.nnn@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('Перезвонить');
$this->email->message($phone);

$mn = $this->email->send();
```

Можно ли проверить с локального сервера(XAMPP), чтоб потом когда на хостинг заливали, проблем не было.И правильно ли таким образом делать?

Comment: `XAMPP` довольно распространен, я думаю там есть почтовый сервер, но подсказывать не возьмусь, думаю стоит вам загуглить как настроить почтовый сервер на XAMPP. По поводу второй части вопроса, а что вы от нас хотите услышать? Вроде нормально, единственное уберите `$this->email->initialize($config);` и выше конфиги, они не нужны.

Comment: путь до своего sendmail пропишите и все должно работать. однако учтите, что некоторые провайдеры интернета блокируют исходящий 25й порт от пользователей.

Comment: @StereoFlo Когда на хостинг буду заливать эти настройки понадобятся?

Comment: @Улан на хостинге, с вероятности в 98% путь до sendmail, будет таким, как у вас в сейчас указано `/usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: @StereoFlo использую ХАMPP. как sendmail настроить. Подробнее прошу напишите. или можно ссылки какие нибудь.

Comment: @Уланк сожалению я его не использую, не помогу в этом